# How to prevent images loading multiple times when fast scrolling a gridview?

Tags: android, gridview, concurrency, scroll, lazy-loading

I have a gridview with thumbnails from sdcard. I use an asynctask to lazy load images. It works perfect when i scroll slowly however when I scroll too fast, different images loading on same grid item multiple times and it takes 6 7 second to finally load the correct image. I tried to check if the position of the view is visible by using getFirstVisiblePosition and getLastVisiblePosition, and this time some of the images never loads.

Comment: https://github.com/antoniolg/MaterialEverywhere/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/antonioleiva/materialeverywhere/HomeActivity.java  that will scroll fine. Picasso lib encapsulates your issues with async and with cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to cache your images ? With LruCache for exemple.
Here is the doc : 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html

And here the official tutorial 
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Quick use to it :

```
LruCache<String, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;
public void onCreate(Bundle b)
{
 .....
final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);

final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;
mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
        @Override
        protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
            // The cache size will be measured in kilobytes rather than
            // number of items.
            return bitmap.getByteCount() / 1024;
        }
    };
....
}
public void addBitmapToMemoryCache(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (getBitmapFromMemCache(key) == null) {
        mMemoryCache.put(key, bitmap);
    }
}
public Bitmap getBitmapFromMemCache(String key) {
    return mMemoryCache.get(key);
}
```

EDIT: 
If you're loading you image asynchronously you have to look this tutorial : 
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html

It shows you how to handle concurrency and cancel current task if one is running

Comment: If i understand your problem is multiple times your image are loaded when you scroll, with a cache you just have to use the cached image or load it once if it's not already cached.

Comment: My problem is, when fast scroll the gridview, multiple asyntask starts, when scroll is fininshed, those different asyntask loads different images into same imageview because gridview uses same view multiple times. So every visible imageview loads 7-8 different images in a 6 7 seconds until last asyntask finishes and loads the correct image!

Comment: Ho I understand see my edit I use this method and it's working perfectly. Just need to follow tutorial step :)